# Application Terminates Without Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

My application terminates in the simulator when it successfully switches to a view. I'm sure its something easy, here is the .m file from the view that terminates the app. Maybe something isnt releasing. It does not throw an error in the console, the page loads, sits for a few seconds, then terminates and throws the mach_msg_trap in the debugger. It will continue if I hit the play button.

```
  @implementation ProspectViewController

@synthesize jsonArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURLURLWithString:@"https://www.mysite.php"];

NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];


self.jsonArray = [jsonData JSONValue]; 


[jsonURL release];
[jsonData release];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
return [jsonArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *Prospects = @"agencyname";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Prospects];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:Prospects] autorelease];
}

// setting the text
cell.text = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"agencyname"];    
self.navigationItem.title = @"Prospects";

// Set up the cell
return cell;

}
```

Comment: ir should be because of either of (or both) these statements [agencyName release];
[lblText release];

Comment: Place [super viewDidLoad]; in the beginning of the method.

Comment: Putting a super viewDidLoad in beginning didnt help. Its throwing a mach msg trap in the debugger under ret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not release jsonurl in viewDidLoad because it is not retained before. Only init-like methods retains the instance, not the static constructors.